# jQuery animate() not animating dynamic menu on click

Tags: jquery

I have this code:
`#menu` is a button and `.hmenu` is a div.
When I click the button, it expands and when I click it again, it disappears. So that works great.

But I want the same function activated when I click a menu item in the .hmenu object.
When I do this: the menuItems object disappears and the div .hmenu goes away with no animation.
What's wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hmenu").hide();
$("#menu").click(function(){
    if($(".hmenu").is(':visible')){
        $(".menuItems").hide();
        $(".hmenu").animate({height: "2px"});
        $(".hmenu").animate({width: "2px"});
        $(".hmenu").delay(900).slideUp(400);

    }else{
        $(".hmenu").slideDown(400);
        $(".hmenu").animate({height: "300px"});
        $(".hmenu").animate({width: "160px"});
        $(".menuItems").show();

    }
});
$(".hmenu a").click(function() {
        $(".menuItems").hide();
        $(".hmenu").animate({height: "2px"});
        $(".hmenu").animate({width: "2px"});
        $(".hmenu").delay(900).slideUp(600);
})
})
```

My HTML (it's split up with PHP)

```
        <body class="grad">
        <div class="container">
        <input id="menu" type="button" value="Menu"/>

        <div class="hmenu">
        <ul class="menuItems">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="form_weights.php">Weights</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your html too?

Comment: and can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You can use `$(this)` for changing the css on the menuItem selected

Comment: BTW here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/X5NGM/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly without seeing the HTML, but my guess is that your .hmenu element is shrinking by itself when you call $(".menuItems").hide();

What you should do is just animate the .hmenu container directly without showing/hiding the .menuItems

One additional tip. You can do multiple animations in one function call, like so:

```
//Instead of this:
$(".hmenu").animate({height: "2px"});
$(".hmenu").animate({width: "2px"});

 //do this:
 $(".hmenu").animate({
    height: "2px",
    width: "2px"
 });
```